# React app using react-router is not rendering home component when uploading to gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

Things I've tried so far:

Changed `"start_url": ".",` to `"start_url": "/",` and `"start_url": "/index.html",`

Imported the router using `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`

`exact path` on all my routes

Changed the home path from "/" to "/home" then redirected from "/" to "/home"

Right now it's saying "site not found" but it was working on a lot of the other deployment attempts I made. Every other route usually works properly except for the landing page

App component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import DataContextProvider from './contexts/DataContext.js';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <DataContextProvider>
                <Router>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </DataContextProvider>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "authentication",
    "homepage": "https://dmm22.github.io/authentication",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "gh-pages": "^3.2.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "short_name": "React App",
    "name": "Create React App Sample",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
            "type": "image/x-icon"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo512.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Most recent deployment: https://dmm22.github.io/authentication/

Github repo: https://github.com/dmm22/authentication

Answer (score 0):

The create react app documentation says that:

> GitHub Pages doesn’t support routers that use the HTML5 `pushState`
> history API under the hood (for example, React Router using
> `browserHistory`). This is because when there is a fresh page load for a
> url like http://user.github.io/todomvc/todos/42, where `/todos/42` is a
> frontend route, the GitHub Pages server returns 404 because it knows
> nothing of `/todos/42`. If you want to add a router to a project hosted
> on GitHub Pages, here are a couple of solutions:
>
> - You could switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes. If you use React Router, you can switch to `hashHistory` for this effect, but the URL will be longer and more verbose (for example, http://user.github.io/todomvc/#/todos/42?_k=yknaj). [Read more](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) about different history implementations in React Router.

Therefore you should use `hashHistory` if you want to host your site on GitHub Pages.
Here is the [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing) to documentation.

If you don't wish to change router, try deploying it on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/with/react/) which is also another free hosting provider. But again for Netlify deployment, follow the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify), which says:

To support `pushState`, make sure to create a `public/_redirects` file with the following rewrite rules:

```
/*  /index.html  200
```